# $ \mathbb{Z}_{2} \times S_{3} \simeq D_{6} $

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

I want to know if my proof is correct and if there is some easier way to do it.
I'm studying groups for the first time and am currently seeing Homomorphism Theorem.

$ D_{6} = \langle a,b | a^{2}=b^{6}=e , ab = b^{-1}a \rangle $
$ \mathbb{Z}_{2} \times S_{3} = \{ (i,id),(i,\alpha),(i,\beta),(i,\beta^2),(i,\alpha \beta), (i,\alpha \beta^2) | i = 0_{2},1_{2}\} $

I'm calling $\alpha = (1,2), \beta = (1,2,3)$

Let $f:\mathbb{Z}_2 \times S_{3} \rightarrow D_{6}$ be a function such that:

$f((1_{2},\alpha)) = a$

$f((1_{2},\beta)) = b$

Then $f((1_{2},\alpha))^2 = f((1_{2},\beta))^6 = e$ is satisfied.

$f((1_{2},\alpha))f((1_{2},\beta))f((1_{2},\alpha))=aba$

$f((1_{2},\beta))^{-1} = f((1_{2},\beta)^{-1}) = f((1_{2},\alpha \beta)) = b^{-1}$

Since $ ((1_{2},\alpha))((1_{2},\beta))((1_{2},\alpha)) = (1_{2},\beta)^{-1}$

Then

$ f((1_{2},\alpha))f((1_{2},\beta))f((1_{2},\alpha)) = f((1_{2},\beta))^{-1}$

Then these three conditions will generate a group with same structure as $D_6$ $\square$

Comment: Please someone verify if my edited proof is an homomorphism (different than the one presented by spinoza)

Comment: Your new $f$ is a homomorphism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that $\alpha\beta$ has order $2$. Hence $(1_2,\alpha\beta)$ has order $2$. For $f$ to be a homomorphism, we need 
$$e=f(0_2,id)=f((1_2,\alpha\beta)^2)=(f(1_2,\alpha\beta))^2,
$$ so that $f(1_2,\alpha\beta)$  has order $2$, but $b$ has order $6$. It follows that there is no homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}_2\times S_3\to D_6$ that maps $(1_2,\alpha\beta)$ to $b$.

Consider instead the homomorphism 
$$
g:D_6\to \mathbb{Z}_2\times S_3
$$ 
such that
$$g(a)=(0_2,\alpha)$$
and
$$g(b)=(1_2,\beta).$$

We need to check that the relations of the dihedral group are satisfied:
(1)
$$
(0_2,id)=(0_2,\alpha)^2=(g(a))^2=g(a^2)=g(e);
$$
and (2)
$$
(0_2,id)=(1_2,\beta)^6=(g(b))^6=g(b^6)=g(e);
$$
and (3)
$$
(0_2,id)=((0_2,\alpha)(1_2,\beta))^2=(g(ab))^2=g((ab)^2)=g(abab)=g(e).
$$

This will show that $g$ is a homomorphism.

To show that $g$ is an isomorphism, we can show that 
$$g(x)=(0_2,id)\implies x=e,$$
 and that $|D_6|= |\mathbb{Z}_2\times S_3|.$

Comment: Yes, you are correct. My mistake.

Comment: Just noted that I screwed up my writting so badly. Gonna edit.

Comment: Can I write another homomorphism mapping $a$ to $(1_{2},\alpha)$ as in my edited proof?

Comment: Yes, since the same relations are satisfied.